# Iterate array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

```
  allInfo.map((name) => console.log("arr", name.firstName))
```

The above statement is an array. I want to iterate the values and put them in the following array to show it in the dropdown.

```
    const info = [
        { value: "firstName", label: "firstName" },
        { value: "first",label: "first"},
        { value: "lastName", label: "lastName" }
    ]
```

I want to iterate the value of `allInfo` and put it inside the value of `info`. Instead of `value = "firstName"`, I want to get it from the `allInfo` array. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just map the `allInfo` array directly to get the `info` array.

```js
const info = allInfo.map(name => ({
    value: name.firstName,
    label: name.firstName,
}));
```

If you want to have some static values in the `info` array too, you can use the spread operator like this:

```js
const allInfoItems = allInfo.map(name => ({
    value: name.firstName,
    label: name.firstName,
}));

const info = [
    { value: 'something', label: 'something' },
    ...allInfoItems
]
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, but I also want to put some static values inside this info, since I'll fetching this data in a dropdown. Some values I am getting from the backend while some are static. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: is it possible to have the const info containing static value also and values iterated from allInfo also? Because some values I am getting from the backend, while some are static in UI

Comment: Use the spread operator then - I've added it to the answer.